# I am doing image processing in Python and TensorFlow I try to create TF_Record file it give error

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tfrecord, protoc

I already install protoc3 and my Python version is 3.6. I already created the CSV file using that I have to create TF_record.

```
anoj@anoj-Lenovo-G50-80:~/**PycharmProjects/untitled1/venv$ python3 tf_Record.py --csv_input=data/train_labels.csv  --output_path=train.record**
```

this is my error

```
*Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tf_Record.py", line 99, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/home/anoj/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 125, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "tf_Record.py", line 90, in main
    tf_example = create_tf_example(group, path)
  File "tf_Record.py", line 45, in create_tf_example
    encoded_jpg = fid.read()
  File "/home/anoj/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 125, in read
    self._preread_check()
  File "/home/anoj/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 85, in _preread_check
    compat.as_bytes(self.__name), 1024 * 512, status)
  File "/home/anoj/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 528, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: /home/anoj/PycharmProjects/untitled1/venv/images/20081023231835!Hk-p9s-1; No such file or directory*
```